# Regular Expressions - combine greedy and lazy mode

Tags: regex

For example, for a string:

```
http://www/host/a/b/c/topic/d/e/f/topic/last.html
```

I want to get value of "b" and "c", which are value of string before FIRST "topic".

If I use: `.+/(.+)/(.+)/topic/(.+)`, I will get "e" and "f". I know it is greedy mode, so it matched second "topic". But if I changed to lazy mode, like `.+?/(.+?)/(.+?)/topic/(.+)`, it was still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use something more like:

```
[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/topic/(.+)
```

The idea is instead of matching *any* character, you match up to the next slash. The brackets, `[]`, define a character class, the tilde, `~`, means 'not', so `[^/]` matches everything except a slash.

Comment: It works. use this one "([^/]+)/([^/]+)/topic/(.+)". thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this?

```
^.+?/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/topic
```

Here is a demonstration: http://rubular.com/r/F97qwqjLRj